# php array from mysql not working

Tags: php, arrays, loops, variables, foreach

I'm not an expert in php and mysql, but i'm trying and I have one problem to solve but am kind of stuck...

I want to show to user a multiselect menu with checked selections that he previosly made and wich are stored in mysql. The problem with my code, I'm shure, is in foreach loop. The selections that the user has pre-made are stored in format **1,2,3,4** etc... and now I need this preselected option to be checked as he is trying to edit his information.

The selection of his choise is saved in one sql table and all the options are in a seperate table. I hope that I writen this so you can understand. Thx for your help. Below is my code so far, it is working, but in this case which the user have 4 preselected options, everything is showing 4 times in our multi select...

```
$skupine = mysql_real_escape_string($rows_blog['sku_id']);
$skupine_id = explode(',',$skupine);

echo "<select name='skupina[]' multiple='multiple'>";

$sql_skupina = "SELECT sku_id, title FROM skupine ORDER BY sku_id DESC";
$result_skupina = mysql_query($sql_skupina);

while ($row_skupina = mysql_fetch_array($result_skupina)) {

foreach ($skupine_id as $value){

echo '<option value="'.$row_skupina['sku_id'].'"'.    (!strcmp($row_skupina['sku_id'],$value)?' 
selected':'').'>'.$row_skupina['title'].'</option>';
}
}       
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: How is `$rows_blog` being populated?

Comment: the preselected ids are inserted like this:
$skupine = $_POST['skupina'];
$skupine_id = implode(',',$skupine);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your `foreach` loop (don't forget the closing brace too) and instead of `strcmp`, use `in_array`.

```
echo '<option value="'.$row_skupina['sku_id'].'"'.    (in_array($row_skupina['sku_id'], $skupine_id)?' 
selected':'').'>'.$row_skupina['title'].'</option>';
```

The result will be that if `$row_skupina['sku_id']` is one of the pre-selected options (and is therefore in the `$skupine_id` array), that option will be selected in the dropdown.

As a side-note, you should really stop using the `mysql_*` functions and use [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Comment: Thany you so much, it worked like a charm :) and thx for the advice about PDO, I will look into it

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it does what you want :)

Comment: Sidenote: The use of `mysqli_` / PDO are not a safeguards against SQL injection; not on their own that is. Using [**`mysqli_*` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or **PDO** with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) will.